How to add php-pear to a Yocto image using the Kirkstone release?
I'm working with the Kirkstone version of Yocto and trying to include the php-pear package in my custom image. My PHP setup is working fine, and I'm using the php_8.1.29.bb recipe.
Here's the relevant part of my image configuration:
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " apache2 php mariadb asterisk curl php-modphp i2c-tools helloworld lcddisplay dnsmasq sipservice"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "php-cli php-fpm php-cgi openssh bash php-phar"


When I try to add php-pear to my image and run bitbake core-image-minimal, I encounter the following error:
User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
oe-repo: using metadata from Mon 29 Jul 2024 04:42:57 PM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Tue 30 Jul 2024 07:58:42 AM UTC.
No match for argument: php-pear
Error: Unable to find a match: php-pear

It seems that php-pear is not available. However, it is mentioned in the php_8.1.29.bb recipe under PACKAGES. How can I resolve this issue and successfully include php-pear in my Yocto image?
